# Bash ampersand for another shell failing

Tags: bash, shell, kubectl

So I have a bash script that runs perfectly when in the same shell. It has one line plus #!/bin/bash at the top; if I run this one line on the command line I get the files listed in tmp directory. I am running all these commands as root.

```
"kubectl -it exec -c mysql mysql-0 -- bash -c "ls -lah /tmp"
```

When I call the bash script like so it works:

```
 (works) ./z_mysql-init-pv_TEST.sh
```

The problem is here with an ampersand to run in another shell:

```
(FAILS) ./z_mysql-init-pv_TEST.sh &
```

Permissions are set to: -rwxrwxr-x

update: Well I think the issue here is not a bash issue but a KUBECTL call. As @Chris Dood explains it may be that Kubectl is trying to read something from the terminal in some way. Every other thing works perfectly (get, curl, log ...). I don't know but I will continue to explore.

update: I couldn't see the forest for the trees! @SiHa thank you for pointing out what was right in front of me. I was so blinded by saying "This should work!" that I did not believe it was my call that was the issue.

Comment: No output or error message? Also, you say *"with an ampersand to run in another shell"*, but the `&` means "run the current command in the background". Does this help explain your problem? Add a "echo Inside z_mysql-init-pv_TEST.sh` at the top of your script and try it both ways, I bet you get the output. Good luck

Comment: Maybe remove the "-it" from the kubectl command, as this is only required if you want an *i*nteractive *t*ty

Answer (score 2):

Both of the commands given will run the script in a new shell.  The difference is whether that shell runs in the foreground or the background

- without the `&`, the child shell will run in the forground and will be the controlling process of the terminal (and can interact with it normally).  The parent shell will wait for the child to complete before continuing.
- with the `&` the child shell will be created in a new process group, and the parent will retain control of the terminal (and will immediately prompt and not wait for the child.)

So the important difference is which process is controlling process (group) of the terminal and what happens if/when the child tries to access the terminal.  Any process that is in a process group other than the terminal's controlling foreground process group is a "background" process and is limited if it accesses the terminal.

If a background child tries to read from the terminal, it will get a SIGTTIN and be suspended.  Note that this will happen *even* for a non-blocking read.  If a background child tries to write to the terminal, what happens depends on the `tostop` setting of the terminal.  Normally, this will be off, but if it is on and the child tries to write to the terminal it will get a SIGTTOU signal and be suspended.

So the reason your command appear to fail depends on the details of what it is trying to do and your terminal settings.  You can see the latter by running `stty` -- it will print out `tostop` (among other things) if that option is on.

If the problem is that the `kubectl` or other command is trying to read from the terminal, then the only way to make it work is to either give it some option to not do that (perhaps redirect its input from /dev/null), or run it in the foreground.